# Double list Comprehension with range

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list in Python which I'm trying to print the first five elements out of it using list comprehension.

I understand that this has to be done using double list comprehensions. I have the following at the moment:

```
print [[x[i] for x in mylist] for i in range(0,5)]
```

This throws the following error: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.

When I print each one separately, it works out fine. I do `print mylist[0]`, `print mylist[1]` etc...

What is the issue here? I have a feeling that my entire double comprehension is not right. Now here's what I'm thinking:

```
[x for x in range(0,5)]
```

This creates a list of x's for each x in range(0,5). Since this is my index, I nested another list comprehension statement before that as above to do that over my specific list.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mylist[:5]` gives the first 5 elements of `mylist`. (If `mylist` has fewer than 5 elements in it, then `mylist[:5]` will return a list of length `len(mylist)`.) Using a list comprehension here would be overkill.

Comment: You suggest alternative for `[[x[i] for i in range(0,5)] for x in mylist]` and not for `[[x[i] for x in mylist] for i in range(0,5)]` - read carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Provided `myList` contains at least 5 elements, and you really want to use list comprehension, try this:

```
[print (mylist[i]) for i in range (0, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

unutbu's is the best solution.  Performing it using list comprehensions, you'd want

```
[mylist[i] for i in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As for why you are getting the error, if `myList` is a list of tuples, look at it like this:

```
myList = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]

result = []
for i in range(5):
    sub_result = []
    # Here x will be (0, 1), etc.
    for x in myList:
        # Here you are referencing the ith element of your tuple
        # If your tuple doesn't contain that many elements, you get the error
        sub_result.append(x[i])
```

Therefore it is accessing your tuple and not your list. The other solutions all show how to correct this, so definitely vote for one them - this will hopefully just help figure out why it is causing an error :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access indexes that out of range.
It means that your `x` tuple has length < 5.

It happens for data like `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]..]`

x here would be `[1,2,3]`, then `[4,5,6]` etc

when you try `x[5]` - you get Exception

Answer (score 0):

print [mylist[j] for j in [ i for i in range(5)]]

Although @unutbu's approach is much more readable.